# Understanding Sed Usage in Makefile

Tags: sed, make, busybox

I'm trying to understand the usage of the sed command in Linux, specifically when it is being used in a Makefile. I have included the command I'm trying to interpret below. My interpretation so far is that sed is replacing text and is working inside the inittab file, but I really cannot understand exactly what sed is looking for and what is being replaced, in addition to what the various symbols mean. I would ultimately like to 1) understand how this is working and 2) edit this to add a second line of text to the replacement (right now, I believe only one line is sent via sed).

For context, this code snippet I'm trying to understand and edit is from Busybox's busybox.mk. I'm very much a novice when it comes to sed and makefiles, so I appreciate any guidance you can provide!

`$(SED) '/# GENERIC_SERIAL$$/s~^.*#~$(SYSTEM_GETTY_PORT)::respawn:/sbin/getty -L $(SYSTEM_GETTY_OPTIONS) $(SYSTEM_GETTY_PORT) $(SYSTEM_GETTY_BAUDRATE) $(SYSTEM_GETTY_TERM) #~' \$(TARGET_DIR)/etc/inittab`

Comment: run `make -n` it would printout each action make should do without doing them. Find your `sed` command in the output - it would be already with all substituions and without escape sequences - much easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

It looks cryptic, but I think it does the following:

```
/# GENERIC_SERIAL$$/ ->   Only apply the subsequent substitution when 
                          the line matches that pattern. And since this 
                          is a Makefile, you need to write `$$` 
                          to have a literal `$`.

s~^.*# ->                 Match anything (`.*`) zero or more characters, but 
                          it should include the `#` symbol at the end. 
                          This uses `~` as a separator instead of the 
                          most common `/`
~$(SYSTEM_GETTY_PORT)...
 $(SYSTEM_GETTY_TERM) #~ -> and replace it with this horrific line 
                          including Makefile variables that should be defined 
                          elsewhere or passed as flags.

\$(TARGET_DIR)/etc/inittab -> obviously, this is the file in which the
                          previous substitution should be applied.
```

In summary, `sed /<pattern>/s~<match>~<replacement>~ <file>`